# Finding class average and number of student per subject

Tags: sql-server

How can I get column for class average per subject and column for `No. of students` offering each subject? I have created the following tables statement and queries. Below is my query that gives me the result of a student without class average and `No. of students` per subject.

Table Student has three columns containing three students

```
Studentid   Firstname   Lastname
--------------------------------
1          Oreofeoluwa  Ogunkoya
2          Prevailer    Adebayo
3          Arike        Adeladan
4          Khalilat     Yakubu
```

Table course contains four courses Irk and Crk are optional.

```
Courseid    Course
------------------
1           Maths
2           English
3           Irk
4           Crk
```

I also have StudentCourse as a junction table for course and student. It contains score for all students.

```
SELECT Course
    ,Score
    ,Grade
    ,Comment
    ,Pos
    ,Minimum
    ,Maximum
FROM (
    SELECT S.firstname
        ,S.lastname
        ,C.course
        ,Sc.score
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 80
                    AND 100
                THEN 'A'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 70
                    AND 79
                THEN 'B'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 60
                    AND 69
                THEN 'C1'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 50
                    AND 59
                THEN 'C2'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 40
                    AND 49
                THEN 'D'
            ELSE 'F'
            END AS Grade
        ,CASE 
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 80
                    AND 100
                THEN 'Excellent'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 70
                    AND 79
                THEN 'Very Good'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 60
                    AND 69
                THEN 'Good'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 50
                    AND 59
                THEN 'Average'
            WHEN Score BETWEEN 40
                    AND 49
                THEN 'Pass'
            ELSE 'Fail'
            END AS Comment
        ,Rank() OVER (
            PARTITION BY course ORDER BY Score DESC
            ) AS Pos
        ,Min(Score) OVER (
            ORDER BY course
            ) AS Minimum
        ,Max(Score) OVER (
            ORDER BY course
            ) AS Maximum
    FROM Student S
    JOIN Studentcourse Sc ON S.Studentid = Sc.Studentid
    JOIN Courses C ON C.courseid = Sc.Courseid
    ) sub
WHERE firstname = 'Oreofeoluwa'
```

This query gives me the following table but i need the class average and no of students offering each subject

```
Course  Score   Grade   Comment Pos Minimum Maximum
---------------------------------------------------
Crk     62.00   C1      Good    1   44.00   62.00
English 80.00   A   Excellent   1   43.00   80.00
Maths   96.00   A   Excellent   1   36.00   96.00
```

Comment: Why not just use a window function using `AVG()` with a partition on course? You're already using other window functions.

Comment: I used the  window function clue from BJones and it  worked Thanks a lot. Avg(Score)Over(Partition by course Order by course) As ClassAve, Count(Sc.studentid)Over(Partition by course order by course)As NoOfStudent

Answer (score 0):

You have to group it at the course level to get the average scores at a course level. Please find below a sample query:

```
Select course,avg(score) as avg_score,count(distinct studentid) as students
from Student S
JOIN Studentcourse Sc ON S.Studentid = Sc.Studentid
JOIN Courses C ON C.courseid = Sc.Courseid
Group by course
```

If you want this added to the table you have created at a student level, then you will have to perform a left join. Hope this helps.